# How can I pass in a parameter to RegexParsers in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

Let's say I have this RegexParsers function parsing a simple x=value statement:

```
def term: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z0-9"']+""".r ^^ { _.toString }
def assign: Parser[(varLabel, ValueThing)] = term <~ "=" ~ term ^^ {
  case v ~ t => (v, ValueThing(t))
}
```

Simple enough. Ok, let's say the value assigned (the 2nd term) needs to be parsed according to the label (the first term)?

Somehow I'd like to parse the first term and somehow pass it into the parser for the 2nd term -- conditional parsing, in other words.  Maybe I have a lookup table of Parsers and based on 'x' I look up the right Parser to parse the assigned value.

(So why don't I just use '|'?  Because it's context-free.  I may have >1 sub-parsers for the assigned value that would work--that parse a double value for example.  One just parses double, while another parses a double with an optional text term.  Both work for a naked double w/o the term.  If I knew what the 'x' was in 'x=2.34' then I'd know whether to parse the 2.34 as a naked double or a double w/o it's optional term.  Maybe not a great example, but I have a lot of these kinds of things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parser combinators are so cool!  There's something called into, with abbrev >> that does this.  Looks like this:

```
  def assign: Parser[Int] = (term <~ "=") >> (target => lookup(target))      

  def one: Parser[Int] = term ^^ { 
    case s => if(s == "hey") 1 else 0
  }    
  def two: Parser[Int] = term ^^ { 
    case s => if(s == "you") 100 else -100
  }
  val lookup = Map("x" -> one, "y" -> two)
```

Stupid example but shows the point:  You can grab the first term then use that value to subsequently parse further, in my case looking up a "handler" parser from a table. Of course the selection logic and sub-parsers can be much more complex.